# How do I define the frame of my rectangle in C

Tags: c

I have a question about a task that was given to us by our professor. The task we got is L6 on this website: http://www.juergenbrauer.org/teaching/programming1/programming1.html#L6

> #### L6: Drawing a rectangle
>
> Write a C program that asks the user to enter the height and width of an rectangle and then draws a corresponding rectangle:
>
> ```
> Height of rectangle? 10
> Width of rectangle? 20
> ####################
> #                  #
> #                  #
> #                  #
> #                  #
> #                  #
> #                  #
> #                  #
> #                  #
> ####################
>
> Height of rectangle? 5
> Width of rectangle? 30
> ##############################
> #                            #
> #                            #
> #                            #
> ##############################
>
> Height of rectangle? 10
> Width of rectangle? 40
> ########################################
> #                                      #
> #                                      #
> #                                      #
> #                                      #
> #                                      #
> #                                      #
> #                                      #
> #                                      #
> ########################################
> ```

Now I have written this code so far:

```
int main()
{
    int height;
    int width;
    int a;
    int b;

    printf("Height of rectangle? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &height);

    printf("Width of rectangle? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &width);

    for (a = 0;a != height;a++)
    {
        {
            for (b = 0; b != width; b++)
                if ((a == 0))
                {
                    printf("#");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("");
                }
        }
    }

    _getch();
}
```

I know that in the output `a == 0` will be the first line, `a == 1` the second, and so one. But I can't imagine how to define the width that there is only one "#" at the beginning or the start of for example line 2.

Can you help?

So i found a solution with the help of a friend the algorithm was nearly complete. Thnak you for helping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int height;
    int width;



    printf("Height of rectangle? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &height);

    printf("Width of rectangle? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &width);


    for (int a = 1;a <= height;a++)
    { 
            for (int b = 1; b <= width; b++)
            {


                if ((a == 1) || (a == (width) || (b == 1) || (b == (height))))
                {
                    printf("#");
                }
                else
                    printf(" ");

        }
            printf("\n");
    }



    _getch();
}
```

Comment: the beginning of the line would be `b==0`, why don't you just test for that?

Comment: For width w and height h:  (1) print the first line, which is w `#`  (2) print the middle h-2 lines, which are (a) one `#`, (b) w-2 spaces, (c) one `#`  (3) print the last line, which is w `#`.  Done.

Comment: The use of `for (...) { {` with two statement blocks is unusual.  Not technically wrong, but no experienced C programmer would write that.  They would probably put the inner `{` and `}`  around the body of the inner `for` loop (though that too isn't technically necessary at the moment).  When fixing logic (as opposed to cosmetics), you'll need to think what happens if the user enters a height of 2, or 1, or indeed 0 or a negative number, or if the user types 'elephant' instead of a number.  Similarly for the width.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm looks fundamentally close. (although there are some syntax problems that may result in unexpected results) In your code snippet, you have two open curly brackets following each other.  The second should probably follow the `for` statement:

```
   // { ///move this...
        for (b = 0; b != width; b++)
        {// ...here
            if ((a == 0))
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("");
            }

   /*->*/}  // aligned with its mate above
```

In the algorithm part, you just need to include the end points in each of the condition statements.  The following is a compileable example of how to implement:

```
int main()
{
    int height;
    int width;
    int a;
    int b;
    char q = 'a';

    while (q != 'q')
    {

        printf("Height of rectangle? ");
        scanf(" %d", &height);

        printf("Width of rectangle? ");
        scanf(" %d", &width);


        for (a = 0;a < height;a++)
        {
                for (b = 0; b < width; b++)
                {

                    if((a==0)||(a==(height-1))) // top and bottom lines
                    {
                        printf("#");
                    }
                    else //all other lines
                    {
                         if((b==0) || (b==(width-1))) printf("#");
                         else printf(" ");
                    }               
                }
                printf("\n"); // end of each line

        }
        printf("\n\nEnter q to quit, or any other key to Continue:\n");
        scanf(" %c", &q);
    }
    return 0; // should always include a return value for a non-void function, such as this one
}
```

The syntax problem is with the curly braces.  `{for()...  }` for the inner loop are placed incorrectly.  Should be `for(){...}`

Comment: do i need to nest the second if else condition? cause i tried it without and get all the output in the first line. And if i need to nest it could you explain me why?

Comment: oh yeah you're right the syntax was wrong but the program compiled even with the wrong syntax btw im using visual studio 2k15

Comment: Not sure my last comment (deleted) captured the error correctly.  I am looking at it now....

Comment: where do i have to add the \n because if i write it in the first if-else condition like printf("#\n"); it would make a break after each "#" also in the first line or?

Comment: @LukasWegner - I worked it out.  I was using `width` or `height` sometimes I should have been using the opposite.  The loop shown should get you there.  Replace that section in your code and test it out.  Note the "\n" is outside the inner loop.

Comment: In the `else if ((b == 0)||(b == (width-1)))` section, you could avoid the inner condition since you print the same thing regardless, could you not?  Also, the inner condition in the `else` clause is unnecessary; the cases where a `#` would be printed have been captured by the outer `if` and `else if` statements, have they not?  Also, note that the odd bracing in the code is not wrong AFAICS; it is just very aconventional.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes, thank you!  I was actually looking at that as you were commenting, and noticed the redundancy.  Have edited out the middle section.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a solution that is perhaps more complex on the surface, but that has great flexibility:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void draw_line(int width, char end, char middle)
{
    assert(width > 0);
    int w = 0;
    putchar(end);
    for (w = 1; w < width - 1; w++)
        putchar(middle);
    if (w < width)
        putchar(end);
    putchar('\n');
}

static void draw_rectangle(int height, int width, char border, char fill)
{
    assert(height > 0);
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        draw_line(width, border, (h == 0 || h == height - 1) ? border : fill);
}

static void test_drawing(int height, int width)
{
    printf("%dx%d:\n", height, width);
    draw_rectangle(height, width, '#', ' ');
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    // Testing small sizes, including degenerate cases
    for (int height = 1; height < 6; height++)
    {
        for (int width = 1; width < 6; width++)
            test_drawing(height, width);
    }

    // Testing examples from question
    test_drawing(10, 20);
    test_drawing( 5, 30);
    test_drawing(10, 40);
    return 0;
}
```

It uses functions — lots of functions.  But it also gives flexibility.  I was able to test the small-size degenerate and near-degenerate cases easily, and the 3 examples from the question text — all without having to type a thing while the program is running.  If I needed to be able to print 'indented boxes', it would be easy to do that.  If I needed two boxes on a line, that could almost be done — I'd have to remove the `putchar('\n');` from inside `draw_line()`.  By allowing the border and fill characters to be specified, I can control the appearance more easily (and it was easier to count dots than blanks, so using `'.'` in place of `' '` was simple).

Note too that the code deals with special cases; it attempts to come up with a reasonable answer for a width or height of 1.  And it uses `assert()` to head off the 'impossible' cases.

Output:

```
1x1:
#

1x2:
##

1x3:
###

1x4:
####

1x5:
#####

2x1:
#
#

2x2:
##
##

2x3:
###
###

2x4:
####
####

2x5:
#####
#####

3x1:
#
#
#

3x2:
##
##
##

3x3:
###
#.#
###

3x4:
####
#..#
####

3x5:
#####
#...#
#####

4x1:
#
#
#
#

4x2:
##
##
##
##

4x3:
###
#.#
#.#
###

4x4:
####
#..#
#..#
####

4x5:
#####
#...#
#...#
#####

5x1:
#
#
#
#
#

5x2:
##
##
##
##
##

5x3:
###
#.#
#.#
#.#
###

5x4:
####
#..#
#..#
#..#
####

5x5:
#####
#...#
#...#
#...#
#####

10x20:
####################
#..................#
#..................#
#..................#
#..................#
#..................#
#..................#
#..................#
#..................#
####################

5x30:
##############################
#............................#
#............................#
#............................#
##############################

10x40:
########################################
#......................................#
#......................................#
#......................................#
#......................................#
#......................................#
#......................................#
#......................................#
#......................................#
########################################
```

I think you'll find that a number of the proposed solutions do not handle the degenerate cases (where either width or height or both is smaller than 3).

Comment: It is refreshing to see there are apparently still people on this site who enjoy solving problems! (as opposed to complaining they are too elementary to bother with)

Comment: thanks for your solution man but some of the code you used i havent had before in my lectures

Comment: There’s always that risk.  Using functions other than `main()` is important, but it isn’t clear when you learn it. Making code parameter-driven is important.  Testing degenerate and near-degenerate cases is very important.  Doing it without unnecessary user interaction is important.  Think of it as a foretaste of things to come.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a '#' before and after the whitespaces is a special case and can be handled outside the loop.
One way to handle this would be something like the following pseudo-code :

- loop on lines

  - print a '#'
  - loop on columns from 1 to N-2 (instead of 0 to N-1)

    - print a '#' on first and last lines, print a ' ' on all other lines
  - print a '#'

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to two things:

1. How to get the pattern?
2. How to write the usable code to generate those pattern?

You can try these to get the answer.

For the pattern you will see the first and last row will always be same. Printing the w characters.

Now what is the special thing about the other rows? Only prints two characters. Rest are spaces.

- How many characters there are in a row? `w`.
- If 2 of them are `*`..how many are spaces? `w-2`.
- How many lines are there? `h`.

  2. what is the main thing here? Printing characters.

So write a method where you will print the character `c` n times. And reuse it to print `' '` or`*`.

#### Code

```
void printer(int count,char c){
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        printf("%c",c);
}
int main(){
    int width,height;
    scanf("%d%d",&width,&height);
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
        if(i == 0) printer(width,'*');
        else if( i < h-1)printer(1,'*'),printer(height-2,' '),printer(1,'*');
        else  printer(width,'*');
        puts("");
    }
}
```