# How to assign value in 2 Dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

Creating a tile pattern

```
char t1[11][11];
int i=0;
int j=0;

int size = 10;
//Putting "|" for tile1 (0,0) to (11,0)
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    while(j=0)
    {
        t1[i][j] = '|';
    }
}

//Putting "-" for tile1 (0,0) to (0,11)
for(j=1;j<10;j++)
{
    while(i=0)
    {
        t1[i][j] = '-';
    }
}

//PRINTING  "|" for tile1 (0,0) to (11,0)
for(i=0;i<11;i++){
    while(j=0){
        printf("%c \n",t1[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//PRINTING "-" for tile1 (0,0) to (0,11)
for(j=1;j<10;j++)
{
    while(i=0)
    {
        printf("%c "), t1[i][j];
    }
}
```

So basically I want the output to be like the image given.
I declared an array with 11,11 size and I am trying to use loops to assign characters in the array. But for some reason it is not working.

I know I have to use loops so I drew the pattern on a paper and write down the array location and tried to assign using loops.

Comment: `while(j=0)` is assignment and the resultant condition will always be false. Perhaps you meant `while(j==0)`.

Comment: Would you please define "Not working"? Are the characters in the wrong places? Is the screen blank? Are you hitting any errors? What specific part of it don't you understand?

Comment: These type of questions require a row-wise approach i.e. first fill the first row with the desired pattern (be it @, |,- ) then move to the second row and so on. Design your for loop in that manner.

Comment: Have you ever read _[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define the frame of my rectangle in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181828/how-do-i-define-the-frame-of-my-rectangle-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of errors in your program. Let me list down some:

- `j = 0` assigns `0` to `j`, and `j == 0` compares if `j` is equal to `0`.
- You haven't updated the `i` or `j` in inner `while` loops.
- If you want to stick to the exact pattern shown in the picture, you have to eliminate `\n` from `printf("%c \n", t1[i][j]);`.
- `printf("%c "), t1[i][j];` doesn't print `t1[i][j]`. But `printf("%c ", t1[i][j]);` does.
- You're not assigning `@` character in the array anywhere.

Let's re-write your code:

Initialize the array:

```
char t1[11][11];
```

Now, in a loop, assign each element in this `11 x 11` array a character according to the pattern.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++){

        // If its first or last column, then place a | at t1[i][j]
        if (j == 0 || j == 10){
            t1[i][j] = '|';
        }
        // Else If its the first or last row, then place a - at t1[i][j]
        else if (i == 0 || i == 10){
            t1[i][j] = '-';
        }
        // Else if its the second or second to last row/column
        // then place @ at t1[i][j]
        else if (i == 1 || i == 9 || j == 1 || j == 9){
            t1[i][j] = '@';
        }
        // Else if its the diagonal, then place a @ at t1[i][j]
        else if (i == j){
            t1[i][j] = '@';
        }
        // All remaining places would have a space.
        else{
            t1[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

After this, every element in the array would have been initialized to some appropriate value. Now, print the whole array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
        printf("%c\t", t1[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

See this code running [live here](https://www.ideone.com/2LVh9J).

Answer (score 1):

When you are using

```
printf("%c \n", t1[i][j]);
```

You are writing a character from the array and appending it with a  newline which will break your pattern.
Try changing your printing loops for this one

```
 for (j = 0; j <= 10; ++j)  
 {  
   printf("%s\n" ,t1[j]);  
 }
```

As for writting the '@' characters I would do a loop like that

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; ++i)  
{  
  for (j = 1; j < 10; ++j)    
  {  
    if ((j == 1 || i == 1 || j == 9 || i == 9) || j == i)
      t1[i][j] = '@';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bigger 2D array you can make the code shorter:

```
#define VSIZE 13
#define HSIZE 25

char t1[VSIZE][HSIZE];

for(int i = 0; i < VSIZE ; ++i) {
    for(int j = 1; j < HSIZE - 2; ++j) {
        // default value for odd columns:
        char c = ' ';
        // but change it to something else in an even column:
        if(!(j%2)) {
            if(i == 0 || i == VSIZE - 1)
                c = '-';
            if(i == 1 || i == VSIZE - 2 || 2 * i == j)
                c = '@';
        }
        t1[i][j] = c;
    }
    t1[i][0] = t1[i][HSIZE - 2] = '|';
    t1[i][HSIZE - 1] = '\0';   // turn the row to a string closing it with '\0'

    printf("%s\n", t1[i]);
}
```